# How to display the featured image of a parent on child pages?

Tags: featured-post

I was searching how I can get the featured images of the parent also on the child pages, without uploading it also for the childs.

How can this solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) and pass the ID of the parent instead:

```
if ( $post->post_parent )
    $post_id = $post->post_parent;
else
    $post_id = $post->ID;

if ( $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail' ) ) {
    echo $thumbnail;
}
```